# Should I see local branch/tag folders locally using SVN copy?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to understand an SVN folder structure. I have a repository that has the following folder structure.

```
/tags
/branches
/trunk
```

I have used svn copy to create a tag 1.1 into /tags/1.1 for trunk. I can switch trunk back and forth. I then created a branch for dev as /branches/mydevbranch. I can switch back and forth. After doing so, I see no 1.1 folder in tags or mydevbranch in branches. However, if I look at the repo browser in tortoise SVN I do see the versioned tag and branch. Should I expect to see local files for these version?

Comment: Where you can't see folders? In you WC? But into which root you switched your WC? I suppose, it was **root of branch or tag**, not their parents - check `svn info`

Comment: trunk is my WC, I have 1.1 in tags and mydevbranch in branches. I switch WC trunk. I can switch the WC just fine, but I don't see mydevbranch in branches or 1.1 in tags when I navigate to those folders using windows explorer.

Comment: **Windows** Explorer can't browse SVN-repository (even if you mounted|have repository on local drive) - repository from filesystem-view is just ordinary tree and doesn't reflect repository-tree. You **must** to use Subversion client in order to see repository tree (in repository) - these folders are "virtual"